# How to pass parameters form trigger event to a triggered event in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to pass parameters form 'trigger' event to the triggered event 'click' in Jquery. [Jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-eventType-extraParameters) says that you can pass external parameters in an array 'extraParameters'. However, I don't know who to receive those parameters in the triggered event. 'click' in my case.

The code that I am using to pass parameters in the trigger event is like the following:

```
$("#add_docs").trigger("click", [request_id]);
```

The code that I am using to get the parameters form the 'trigger' event in my 'click' event is like the following:

```
$("#add_docs").click(params, function () { console.log(params[0]) });
```

There is wrong with the way that I am trying to get the params. I need a little help here please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extra arguments are passed sequantially to the callback, beginning from the second argument (the first is the event object).

```
$('button').on('click', function(evt, param1, param2) {
    alert(param1+'-'+param2); //"bar-foo"
})
```

These are then passed as an array via the second param of `trigger()`.

```
$('button').trigger('click', ['bar', 'foo']);
```

Comment: I see, what a stupid mistake.. I completely missed this point

Comment: I will mark you answer as the answer to this question :) Thank you!